# Grid Field Language

Tags: language

I have this grid field which is set for a date (calendar), but when I output the field's date it is printed in English.

I have the dutch language-pack installed, for my Add-On of Low Events EE does print the dates in the dutch language..

Anybody knows why my grid 'date' field prints in English?

Expression Engine v2.8.1 -
Language pack from January 2014

Best regards Dave

Comment: I found the folder you mentioned, but i have stiil two questions now. Do I upload the same language pack here as in /system/expressionengine/language? Do I need to activate or select this in the CP ifso where do I do this. Thanks for your help and advice BTW.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Answer (score 3):

The point is that EECMS uses **two** folders of languages!

One is `/system/expressionengine/language/` and the other is `/system/codeigniter/system/language`. Both language packs are completely different.

The dates and the form validation messages are used from the one in the Codeigniter folder.

You can find [CodeIgniter Language Packs on github](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Language-Translation), but I don't know if they match the custom version used on EECMS.

My suggestion is to duplicate the contents of the English folder and translate just the parts you need.

Keep the same name on both folders and they will be activated together.

---

Yeap! This is annoying. I already filled a [bug report about this](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19245/ci-languages-files-on-form-validation-class), but looks like, despite of what the bug report says, it is still relevant:

> This bug report is over one year old and may not be relevant.

Comment: I found the folder you mentioned, but i have stiil two questions now. Do I upload the same language pack here as in /system/expressionengine/language? Do I need to activate or select this in the CP ifso where do I do this. Thanks for your help and advice BTW.

Comment: @Dave_Daliz, I updated my answer. I'm sorry for being unclear in a first moment.